# virtualisation with kvm: export services from guest to the host

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, tun

I would like to export some services from the guest os to the host os, via kvm, and by the same way learn some things about networking.
I have tried the following commands:

### In the host (kubuntu 10.4):

```
$ sudo tunctl -u ascobol
Set 'tap0' persistent and owned by uid 2401
$ sudo ifconfig tap0 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.2.255
```

The ifconfig command returns:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig
tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3e:4e:e3:cc:bc:92  
inet addr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3c4e:e3ff:fecc:bc92/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:17 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)


$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap0
```

Then I run the virtual machine (ubuntu server 10.4):

```
$ sudo  kvm -hda ubuntuserver104.qcow2 -net nic -net tap,name=tap0,script=no
```

(I'm using sudo because without it fails with the following message:)

> warning: could not configure /dev/net/tun: no virtual network emulation

With sudo the virtual machine boots, I just get this message:

> pci_add_option_rom: failed to find romfile "pxe-rtl8139.bin"

### In the virtual machine:

```
$ ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.2.255
```

Now if I run:

```
$ ssh 192.168.2.2
```

I just get a

> No route to host

What is wrong with this setup ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem when the virtual machine was launched:

```
$ sudo  kvm -hda ubuntuserver104.qcow2 -net nic -net tap,name=tap0,script=no
```

I replaced

```
name=tap0
```

by

```
ifname=tap0
```

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

```
pci_add_option_rom: failed to find romfile "pxe-rtl8139.bin"
```

means you have no pxe bootrom images installed. try installing them, or look them up in /usr/share/qemu or /usr/share/gpxe